# How to make pycharm recognize that my file is the jinja2 or tornado template?

Tags: templates, comments, pycharm

I already marked a certain folder as templates in *File>Settings>Project Structure*, but when I press *Ctrl+/* in *.html* file located in this folder the IDE comments line by `<!-- -->` instead of `{# #}`

Thanx in advance.

I'm on Ubuntu Linux 14.04 LTS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to 'Preferences' -> 'Python Template Languages' and select 'Jinja2' from the dropdown menu. That solved it for me.